# How to wait for elements to show up

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using Android Espresso Web to test a web view in an android application.
It takes some time to be done with loading the website. Before I perform the click action on the element I need to wait for it to be displayed.
Any APIs I can use? I don't wanna use sleep() method.

Comment: Why do you wanna use the API's please share more details about the problem you are facing. probably consider posting the stacktrace or any meaningful line.

Comment: This question isn't above Espresso web but you could use a similar approach with a little modification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294132/espresso-doesnt-wait-for-swipe-action-on-a-viewpager-to-be-finished/43908701#43908701

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProgressDialog()` on `WebView()` and set `progressDialog.cancelable(false)`